Creating HTTP Request and Async logout task in AuthController to ensure user is logged out of all windows using C#, ASP.NET Core MVC
I am using C# and ASP.NET Core MVC to use an AuthController to log out of all windows that the application has open. I I then use a public async Task in NotifyClient.cs to complete the request and I have set up a task in the public interface. I am close to getting this to work but require a little help with the C#.
To get this to work I have done as much as I can but I am a little unsure of the flow of the code to get this to work (I have commented in what is meant to happen in pseudo code).
So far the code is as follows:
AuthController:
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string application, Boolean notifyWindows, string callback = "/")
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
    {
        var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key.Contains(".AspNetCore.") || c.Key.Contains("Microsoft.Authentication"));

        foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
        }
    }

    if (notifyWindows == true)
    {
        // todo, get user id
        // todo, call the notification endpoint to inform the FE to logout of all tabs
        // await _notifyClient.UpdateUserLogoutAsync(new UpdateUserLogoutRequest { }, ct);
        _logger.LogError("notifyWindows");
    }

    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();

    return RedirectToAction("Auth0Login", new { callback, application, forceLogin = true });
}

NotifyClient:
public async Task UpdateUserLogoutAsync(UpdateUserLogoutRequest request)
{
    // try
    // {
    //    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"realtimealerts/user/logout/{request.UserId}");
    //    message.Content =
    //        new 
    // }

    // TODO NEW FUNCTION TO LOGOUT 
    // UpdateUserLogoutAsync
}

INotifyClient:
public interface INotifyClient
{
    Task UpdateUserLogoutAsync(UpdateUserLogoutRequest request);
}


If you change the user's SecurityStamp all sessions will be invalidated. But forcing all sessions to be logged out is an unusual requirement.

I assume sending HTTP requests to your notification endpoint and then implement some logic on the frontend to listen for the logout notifications and handle your logging   out function.

@JeremyLakeman How would I implement this with the current code structure I have. would it just be used in the try catch in the NotifyClient?

@FengzhiZhou Yeah, there is already some logic on the front end that listens for the logout notifications. I am just looking to have a function that will notify all the windows that the user is logged into

@Need Help  You can try signalr way to send notifications https://zealousweb.medium.com/signalr-to-send-real-time-notifications-with-asp-net-core-c6c91ccbc640
